# Two-Columns and Equal Height

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

With this markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <article>A</article>
    <article>B</article>
    <article>C</article>
    <article>D</article>
    <article>E</article>
    <article>F</article>
</div>
```

How can I style it to have:

```
|-------|---------|
|       |         |
|   A   |    B    |
|       |         |
|-------|---------|
|       |         |
|   C   |    D    |
|       |         |
|-------|---------|
|       |         |
|   E   |    F    |
|       |         |
|-------|---------|
```

such that each pair should have an equal height? The height should come from the **article** that has the longer content, i.e. if the content in **C** is longer than **D**, then **D** should match the height of **C**.

What I have tried so far is the good old float, but since it's floated then it has variable heights that depends on contents.

I have also googled similar things but what I have found are fixed-height columns that just hide extra contents.

Comment: why dont you use table for that....a very simple way

Comment: It will be a responsive design so no table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use equal height function for that that will worl

```
function equalHeight(group) {
    var tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    equalHeight($(".recent-article"));

});
```

// HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <article class="recent-article">A</article>
    <article class="recent-article">B</article>
    <article class="recent-article">C</article>
    <article class="recent-article">D</article>
    <article class="recent-article">E</article>
    <article class="recent-article">F</article>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP wants equal height per *pair*. So this is slightly off.

Comment: we can use same class for divs which we want to have same height

Comment: If possible, I don't want JS for this.

Comment: Then use table for that, table is best way to create equal height layout

Comment: It's not a tabular data, those are articles so I will not use tables. Besides, I'll make it responsive.

Comment: OK, I think I give up now on not using JS. I thought it can be done using CSS only bec. it seems so simple.

Comment: I think that more reliable way is to use outerHeight().

Answer (score 0):

Better you have to table for this.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <article class="recent-article">A</article>
        </td>
        <td>
            <article class="recent-article">B</article>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <article class="recent-article">C</article>
        </td>
        <td>
             <article class="recent-article">D</article>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <article class="recent-article">E</article>
        </td>
        <td>
            <article class="recent-article">F</article>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```